# is there anything I can do to fix a broken DNS server or is that completely on the ISP end?

Tags: networking, dns

nslookup google.com

DNS request timed out.

timeout was 2 seconds.

Server:  UnKnown

Address:  192.168.1.1

DNS request timed out.

timeout was 2 seconds.

DNS request timed out.

timeout was 2 seconds.

DNS request timed out.

timeout was 2 seconds.

DNS request timed out.

timeout was 2 seconds.

*** Request to UnKnown timed-out

Comment: Change your DNS. https://1.1.1.1/dns/

Comment: It really matters how your DNS server is setup. If your DNS is setup incorrectly, it can result in this. It is also possible that your router is the DNS server and that it forwards all traffic to your ISP, but that the DNS service on your router crashed. In that case, you can simply reboot the router.

Comment: Many/most routers should let you manually specify the DNS servers to use. Or you can configure the network properties of specific machines to use a specific DNS instead of the supplied one. How to set it up would depend on the type of computer and operating system which you have not specified.

Answer (score 2):

> Address: 192.168.1.1
> DNS request timed out.

This suggest that your router is having a problem. It is very likely that your router is setup as a DNS server to cache requests, and that the DNS server service on the router has crashed.

Before doing anything else, reboot your router and then your pc and see if this fixes the issue.